# Limit how many items for a specific choice field are allowed List

Tags: list

I am looking for a solution to let students assign to a class timeslot. I wanted to use the choice column to list the timeslots and then limit the maximum items allowed for this choice by a N number ( e.g. 40 students - maximum room size). Therefore if someone changes or cancels their attendance, that should free up 1 choice, and if the choice was made 40 times, then it is no longer possible to select it.